# delete wget yum source sublime2

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, wget, yum

I think I've add a sublime2 source by wget, but I did not succeed to install it. Then now if I want to install any other software like firefox:

```
yum install firefox
```

I wil  get errors like this:

```
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Repository sublime2 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository sublime2-dev is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository sublime2-nightly is listed more than once in the configuration
G02R02C00                                                | 1.5 kB     00:00     
epel/metalink                                            |  27 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 5.9 MB     00:01     
scl_python27                                             | 3.0 kB     00:00     
standard                                                 | 1.2 kB     00:00     
standard/primary                                         |  28 MB     00:06     
standard                                                            16898/16898
http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/6Server/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: sublime2. Please verify its path and try again
```

I'm confused cause I don't know why this error comes when I try to install any other things.
I run the command

```
sudo find / -name sublime2
```

And I got:

```
/var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server/sublime2
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/sublime2
```

I deleted these two but next time I try to install somthing else, they will show up again!
How can I just delete everything related to `sublime2` completely? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/sublime.repo` (or any other file with similar name) , then it should work.

If you don't find any such file. Then grep for sublime in /etc/yum.repos.d directory. And delete the file.

```
grep "sublime" /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

Another temporary solution is to disable to repository every time you run yum.

```
yum --disablerepo=sublime2 install firefox
```